# MySQL inserting wrong values into table, exclamation point

Tags: mysql

What I'm typing in:

```
INSERT INTO reviews VALUES ('', title='dragon ball z', date='2012-12-01 23:06:03', username='testads1412117947', rating=100, synopsis='lots of fighting', review='i liked it', poster='kk')
```

The first value is a Primary Key ID, and has been fine on all my other files left null.  MySQL only inserts the ID an leaves everything else as 0, but still says everything went fine.

I'm not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO reviews (title, date, username, rating, synopsis, review, poster)
VALUES ('dragon ball z', '2012-12-01 23:06:03', 'testads1412117947', 100, 'lots of fighting', 'i liked it', 'kk')
```

FYI, if it's not already, your Primary Key ID should also be set to AUTO_INCREMENT so that it auto-generates ID values as you insert new rows.

Comment: Awesome.  As juergen pointed out below, you were mixing up UPDATE syntax with INSERT syntax a little.  You should read through that post to note the difference.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO reviews (title, date, username, rating, synopsis, review, poster) VALUES ('dragon ball z', '2012-12-01 23:06:03', 'testads1412117947', 100, 'lots of fighting', 'i liked it', 'kk')

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax to `insert`

```
INSERT INTO reviews (title, date, username, rating, synopsis, review, poster)
VALUES ('dragon ball z', '2012-12-01 23:06:03', 'testads1412117947', 100, 'lots of fighting', 'i liked it', 'kk')
```

for an `update` use

```
update reviews
set title='dragon ball z', 
    date='2012-12-01 23:06:03',
    username='testads1412117947', 
    rating=100, 
    synopsis='lots of fighting', 
    review='i liked it', 
    poster='kk'
where ...
```

but don't mix them up.